# How to interpret the contents of a pytz.timezone

Tags: python, pytz

I recently had a bug in my code because I used `EST` timezone thinking it was the acronym for `US/Eastern`.

From what I now understand, `EST` is `Eastern Standard Time`, and it does not move with DST. The analogue of `EST` is `EDT` (`Eastern Daylight Time`). Neither move with DST. The timezone which does is `US/Eastern`.

As such I wanted to find out the same information about `CET` (`Central European Time`).

I printed the `__dict__` of several timezones, but I'm not sure how to properly interpret the contents.

```
>>> import pytz
>>> import pp

>>> pp(pytz.timezone('CET').__dict__)
{
    '_dst': datetime.timedelta(0),
    '_tzinfos': {
        (datetime.timedelta(0, 3600), datetime.timedelta(0), 'CET'): <DstTzInfo 'CET' CET+1:00:00 STD>,
        (datetime.timedelta(0, 7200), datetime.timedelta(0, 3600), 'CEST'): <DstTzInfo 'CET' CEST+2:00:00 DST>,
    },
    '_tzname': 'CET',
    '_utcoffset': datetime.timedelta(0, 3600),
}

>>> pp(pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin').__dict__)
{
    '_dst': datetime.timedelta(0),
    '_tzinfos': {
        (datetime.timedelta(0, 3180), datetime.timedelta(0), 'LMT'): <DstTzInfo 'Europe/Berlin' LMT+0:53:00 STD>,
        (datetime.timedelta(0, 3600), datetime.timedelta(0), 'CET'): <DstTzInfo 'Europe/Berlin' CET+1:00:00 STD>,
        (datetime.timedelta(0, 7200), datetime.timedelta(0, 3600), 'CEST'): <DstTzInfo 'Europe/Berlin' CEST+2:00:00 DST>,
        (datetime.timedelta(0, 10800), datetime.timedelta(0, 7200), 'CEMT'): <DstTzInfo 'Europe/Berlin' CEMT+3:00:00 DST>,
    },
    '_tzname': 'LMT',
    '_utcoffset': datetime.timedelta(0, 3180),
}
```

- Why does `Europe/Berlin` have **4** `tzinfos`, while `CET` only has 2?
- Does the fact that `CET` have 2 `tzinfos`, one of which mentions `DST` mean that it **does** move when DST is in effect?
- What does `LMT` and `CEMT` mean?

I did the same for `EST` and `US/Eastern`, and `EST` has nothing in its `__dict__` which is somewhat confusing, whereas `US/Eastern` has **5**!

```
>>> pp(pytz.timezone('EST').__dict__)
{}

>>> pp(pytz.timezone('US/Eastern').__dict__)
{
    '_dst': datetime.timedelta(0),
    '_tzinfos': {
        (datetime.timedelta(-1, 68400), datetime.timedelta(0), 'EST'): <DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' EST-1 day, 19:00:00 STD>,
        (datetime.timedelta(-1, 68640), datetime.timedelta(0), 'LMT'): <DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' LMT-1 day, 19:04:00 STD>,
        (datetime.timedelta(-1, 72000), datetime.timedelta(0, 3600), 'EDT'): <DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' EDT-1 day, 20:00:00 DST>,
        (datetime.timedelta(-1, 72000), datetime.timedelta(0, 3600), 'EPT'): <DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' EPT-1 day, 20:00:00 DST>,
        (datetime.timedelta(-1, 72000), datetime.timedelta(0, 3600), 'EWT'): <DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' EWT-1 day, 20:00:00 DST>,
    },
    '_tzname': 'LMT',
    '_utcoffset': datetime.timedelta(-1, 68640),
}
```

Finally, is there a way to get a human readable description of what a timezone "does", as in whether it changes to DST or not, what the offset from UTC is etc?

Comment: Timezone definitions were adjusted over time with new legislation; what you’re looking at there for the most part are *historical* timezones and offsets and when they started and ended.

Comment: @deceze thanks for this. I googled `CEMT`, `EWT` etc and came to this conclusion. As to my question about `CET` changing UTC offset during DST, is this the case please?

Comment: CET is the timezone without DST, CEST the one with, and Europe/Berlin is the “bundle” that switches between CET and CEST at certain times.

Comment: @deceze thank you for this. Why are there 2 `tzinfos` for CET?